# How to change the md-grid-tile disposition

Tags: angular, angular-material2

```
 <md-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="100px">
  <md-grid-tile style="border: 1px solid black"
  *ngFor="let tile of [{cols : 2}, {cols : 2 }, {cols : 2 }, {cols : 1 }]; let index = index"
  [colspan]="tile.cols"
  [style.background]="tile.color">
     tile - {{index}}
 </md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>
```

I want to change the disposition of the cols when the width is <= 500px like this

```
 <md-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="100px">
  <md-grid-tile style="border: 1px solid black"
  *ngFor="let tile of [{cols : 2}, {cols : 2 }, {cols : 2 }, {cols : 2 }]; let index = index"
  [colspan]="tile.cols"
  [style.background]="tile.color">
     tile - {{index}}
 </md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>
```